# how to define linux kernel variable accessed by several source file?

Tags: c++, c, linux, linux-kernel, global-variables

I have searched the answer to my question for hours, to no avail.

**My question:** I want to define a variable that can be accessed(w/r)(shared) by the two files in linux kernel: `source/arch/x86/kvm/x86.c` and `source/kernel/sched/core.c`.

**My failed attempt:** I tried to use `export_symbol` to define a global var in `x86.c`. But the compile error message says:

> the var is undefined reference

Is there any other solution? I am new to linux kernel programming. Thanks in advance.

Comment: solved...a minite after I posted this question...just use export_symbol to define a global var in core.c, not in x86.c. but don't know why? anybody know?

Comment: The order of compiling and linking of files does matter too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use want to use a global variable in kernel modules, you should use the EXPORT_SYMBOL() or EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL() or EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL_FUTURE():
Eg:

```
 int myvar;
 EXPORT_SYMBOL(myvar);
```

you should then use

`extern int myvar`

in the other file where you want to use it, before you use it.

Answer (score 4):

You can think of kernel symbols (either functions or data objects, variables) and their visibility at three different levels in the kernel source code:

```
"static", - visible only within their own source file
"external" - visible to any other code built into the kernel itself
"exported" - visible and available to any loadable module.
```

Also you may want to consider how other module should use your exported symbols, typically done with one of:

```
EXPORT_SYMBOL() - exports to any loadable module, or
EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL() - exports only to GPL-licensed modules.
```

Comment: EXPORT_SYMBOL_GPL_FUTURE() - marks the symbols which may be changed to a GPL-only export at some time in the future